# Making Hidden Input Appear when Specific Select Value is Chosen

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select, paypal

I'm making a custom form to send information to PayPal using the hidden HTML variables. This is more of a jQuery question than PayPal though. I have a `<select>` dropdown and I want a hidden input to appear only when a certain value is chosen for the `<select>` menu. For example:

```
<form class="test_form">
    <select class="test_select">
        <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Let's say, if I choose "test2", I would like a hidden input to appear in the form. This is the code I've used but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
$('.test_form').change(function(){
if ($(".test_select").val() == 'test2'){
     $("#test_form").html("<input type="hidden" name="weight" value="0.22" />");
}
});
</script>
```

What can I do to make this appear in my code when I select the certain value? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note you've got a broken string there - you can see it in the syntax highlighting of `hidden` and `weight`.

Comment: Only thing I can think of outside of ahren's statement is placing it inside of `jQuery(function($){`

Comment: Yup, that and we don't know what `#test_form` is, or whether or not it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rajesh007/apjtd/), Don't just copy and use ,check your mistake

```
$(function(){
    $('.test_select').change(function(){
        if ($(".test_select").val() == 'test2'){
            $(".test_form").append($('<input type="hidden" name="weight" value="0.22" />'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do is keep input in html but make it hidden.Then make it fade in when you like

```
<input type="text" style="display:none" id="hiddeninput">
....
....
<script>
function disp(){
    $('#hiddeninput').fadeIn(1000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
$('.test_select').change(function(){ 
    if ($(".test_select").val() == 'test2'){ 
        $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'hidden',
            value: '0.22',
            name: 'weight'
        }).appendTo('form');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code inside form

```
<div id="test2" class="tests" style="display: none;">
 <input type="text" name="yourname"/>
</div>
```

Change your script to

```
$('.test_select').change(function() {
  $('.tests').slideUp("slow");
  $('#' + $(this).val()).slideDown("slow");
});
```

So if you select test2 it will show the text field, otherwise it will hide the text field